# Embedding matplotlib graph on Tkinter GUI

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, user-interface, tkinter

[image: Embedding matplotlib graph of Tkinter GUI]Good evening every... am learning how to embed matplotlib graph on Tkinter GUI and am not succeeding and I have attached a picture to show you what's happening, please help.
Am getting data from the Arduino serial port (ECG readings), plot it with matplotlib(embedded on Tkinter GUI) but when I run my code below a matplotlib figure is created where the plot is happening.

NOTE THAT MY AIM IS TO PLOT DIRECT ON THE GRAPH THAT IS ON THE GUI AND DON'T WORRY ABOUT THE GRAPH BEEN PLOTTED.

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np
import serial as sr
import time


def start_plot():
    data = np.array([])
    while True:
        a = s.readline()
        a.decode()
        b = float(a[0:4])
        data = np.append(data, b);
        plt.cla()
        plt.plot(data)
        plt.pause(0.01)
    s.close()

main_window = Tk()
main_window.configure(background='light blue')
main_window.iconbitmap('lardmon_icon.ico')
main_window.title("ECG-LArdmon")
main_window.geometry('800x700')
main_window.resizable(width=False, height=False)




plotting_frame = LabelFrame(main_window, text='Real Time', bg='white', width=300, height=440, bd=5, relief=SUNKEN)
controls_frame = LabelFrame(main_window, text='Controls', background='light grey', height=150)

controls_frame.pack(fill='both', expand='1', side=TOP, padx=20, pady=10)
plotting_frame.pack(fill='both', expand='yes', side=BOTTOM, padx=20)


start_button = Button(controls_frame, text='Start Monitoring', width=16, height=2, borderwidth=3, command=start_plot)
start_button.pack(side=LEFT, padx=26)

exit_button = Button(controls_frame, text='Close', width=10, height=2, borderwidth=3, command=main_window.destroy)
exit_button.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=26)



s = sr.Serial('COM3', 9600)
fig = Figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_title("Electrocadiogram")
ax.set_xlabel("Time(Sec)")
ax.set_ylabel("Voltage(mV)")
ax.set_xlim(0, 200)
ax.set_ylim(-0.5, 6)
ax.grid(b=True, which='major', color='#666666', linestyle='-')
ax.minorticks_on()
ax.grid(b=True, which='minor', color='#666666', linestyle='-', alpha=0.2)
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=plotting_frame)
canvas.get_tk_widget().place(x = 0, y = 0, width = 600, height = 420)
canvas.draw()

main_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Reason is simple: your function is not plotting on the `Figure` and `ax` you already created. Instead, you are calling `plt.plot`, which creates a new instance and also runs on a separate thread. Also note that a `while` loop will freeze your GUI.

Comment: @HenryYik that's where am getting confused, how can I go about fixing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You already created a `Figure` object and an `ax`, so always plot on it and update your `canvas`.
2. Use `tkinter.after` method to call your function recursively so it won't freeze your GUI.

Below are the minimum changes required to showcase how it can be done:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np

from tkinter import *

data = []

def start_plot():
    data.append(np.random.uniform(0, 5))
    ax.plot(data, color="blue")
    canvas.draw_idle()
    main_window.after(100, start_plot) # in milliseconds, 1000 for 1 second

# no change to the rest
....
```

Comment: Thank brother for the help you've really saved my life and blessings all the way.